# Regarding unessential information between commas

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am trying to write the following sentence:

*And I, like the Bedouin, am engaged in the search of that oasis, whose waters will lift me into eternity.*

I want to know, whether the unessential element (*like the Bedouin*) should succeed or precede the verb (*am*).

Comment: There are several acceptable places for the parenthetical adjunct. _And[,] like the Bedouin, I am engaged in the search of that oasis, whose ... // And I, like the Bedouin, am engaged in the search of that oasis, whose ... // And I am, like the Bedouin, engaged in the search of that oasis, whose ... // And I am engaged in the search of that oasis, like the Bedouin – that oasis whose waters will lift me into eternity. // And I am engaged in the search of that oasis whose waters will lift me into eternity – like the Bedouin._ Different emphases may be imposed; your first suggestion sounds fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your placement is correct. 
Having "I" and "like the Bedouin" directly adjacent strengthens the association of similarity between them.